# C: printing a number with 0(08) at first using printf and scanf functions

Tags: c, printf

How can I print an integer with a zero at first.
for example scanning time information from `stdin`:

```
int h, m;
scanf("%d:%d", &h, &m);
printf("%d:%d", h, m);
```

I scanned 08:19, it puts 8:19, how to change its form?

Comment: A [good `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) might help.

Answer (score 3):

For minimal 2 digits and leading 0 try:

```
printf("%02d:%02d",h,m);
```

Answer (score 1):

`%0d` is what you are after

`printf("%0d:%0d",h,m);`

Comment: Are you sure of your answer?

Comment: sure i'm ;) deleting that `perhaps`

Answer (score 1):

tpr's answer is the classic way to do this, but you might consider:

```
printf("%.2d:%.2d", h, m);
```

It will print the same `08:09` output for `h=8` and `m=9`.

The precision field for `printf` integer formatting specifies the minimum number of digits to produce.  If you want to pad the number in addition to leading zeroes, you can use both width and precision:

```
printf("|%3.2d:%-3.2d|", h, m);
```

will produce `| 08:09 |`.

Another interesting property is the ability to produce no output for zero values:

```
printf("|%3.0d|", 0);
```

will produce `|   |`, very handy sometimes.